# sending json from local laravel apps to production laravel apps

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

first of all sorry for question title that may sound weird.. it is the best i can get to sum up what i want to ask..

so here is the problem, i have laravel apps in my cloud server (which from now on i will called it lara-online) and laravel apps my local/localhost/computer (which i will called it lara-offline)

**Question**

what i want it do is i use lara-offline with firebird package to read firebird database in local computer and then send those data to laravel-online via an api route that i created in laravel-online that just receive json data from there...

i have been looking around and can't find anything about it.. so maybe someone can point out a simple example...

**why i do that?**

well because i need to read firebird database, and uploading to laravel-online is not practical since it is big and this firebird database is being used by other desktop app in a lot of computer client everywhere, and i just thinking maybe i can put laravel-offline in every computer client and using windows task to just make it run firefox or chrome and open some route that do reading firebird and sending those data into laravel-online.